# Changing 1-3 random index(s) in a sequence to a random value

Tags: clojure, sequence

I would also like the changed value to be random. For example

```
'(1 2 3 4 5)
```

one possible output.

```
'(1 3 3 4 5)
```

another

```
'(1 5 5 4 5)
```

Comment: What have you tried? https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc? https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rand-int?

Comment: I know how to use rand-int. Assoc doesn't work on sequences. I have tried replace, and update but those also don't work with sequences in this way.

Comment: Maybe https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk-replace... I'm not too sure...

Comment: No postwalk doesn't work with sequences. Thanks though.

Comment: is there something preventing you from using a vector instead of a sequence? vectors work with `assoc`

Comment: well yes and no. I guess I should have mentioned that I actually want to change 1-3 values in the sequence. I thought if I could change one value I could use repeatedly. Repeatedly doesn't work with vectors and it throws an error if you try to convert it. I will change the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

there are more idiomatic ways to do this in clojure. For example this one:

you can generate infinite lazy sequence of random changes to the initial collection, and then just take a random item from it.

```
(defn random-changes [items limit]
  (rest (reductions #(assoc %1 (rand-int (count items)) %2)
                    (vec items)
                    (repeatedly #(rand-int limit)))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (take 5 (random-changes '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) 100))
([1 2 3 4 5 64 7 8] [1 2 3 4 5 64 58 8] [1 2 3 4 5 64 58 80] 
 [1 2 3 4 5 28 58 80] [1 2 3 71 5 28 58 80])

user> (nth (random-changes '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) 100) 0)
[1 2 3 64 5 6 7 8]
```

and you can just take an item at the index you want (so it means collection with `index + 1` changes).

```
user> (nth (random-changes '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) 100) (rand-int 3))
[1 46 3 44 86 6 7 8]
```

or just use `reduce` to take the n times changed coll at once:

```
(defn random-changes [items limit changes-count]
  (reduce #(assoc %1 (rand-int (count items)) %2)
          (vec items)
          (repeatedly changes-count #(rand-int limit))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (random-changes [1 2 3 4 5 6] 100 3)
[27 2 33 4 76 6]
```

also you can just associate all the changes in a vector at once:
`(assoc items 0 100 1 200 2 300)`, so you can do it like that:

```
(defn random-changes [items limit changes-count]
  (let [items (vec items)
        rands #(repeatedly changes-count (partial rand-int %))]
    (apply assoc items
           (interleave (rands (count items))
                       (rands limit)))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (random-changes [1 2 3 4 5 6] 100 3)
[1 65 61 44 5 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me a more proper way of solving this is clojure. I did ask for a sequence in sequence out solution like mine below. Which was my main issue. I suppose I could solve that by calling converting it to a vector before entering it into this function then reconverting it after.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Decided to go a longer route and make a function.

```
(defn changeSequence
[sequ x]
(def transsequ (into [] sequ))
(if (> x 0)
(changeSequence (assoc transsequ (rand-int (count transsequ)) (rand-int foo)) (dec x))
(seq sequ)
))
```

Comment: It is bad form to `def` within a function. Are you trying to redefine `transsequ` every time you call `changeSequence`? It is also poor form to name functions in CamelCase, more idiomatic to use lowercase and hyphen punctuation (i.e. `(defn change-sequence [...]...)`)